# capture content in html comments with regex

Tags: html, ruby, regex, comments

I need to capture markup (html) with regex in **ruby** (yep I know this is bad, but I havent found any alternative as the original markup is really bad formatted).
So I have an original document which looks like this:

```
<h3 class="grey" style="font-size:18pt;"><!-- #BeginEditable "Title" -->Sample Title
<!-- #EndEditable --></h3>



<!-- #BeginEditable "Text" --><p>Foo bar </p>
<p>
</p><ul>
<li>Sample li</li>
<p></p>
<blockquote dir="ltr" style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px">
<p>Foo bar<span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor</span></p></blockquote>
<!-- #EndEditable -->
```

As i cannot change the original markup (and there are no meaningful classes at all!), i decided to try some regex magic.

I tried to capture the content within the comments with a regex like so:

```
<!-- #BeginEditable "(Title|Text|Foo)" -->\s*([^!]+)\s*<!-- #EndEditable -->
```

Obviously this fails when there is a `!` inside the markup, however using `.*` to capture the content inside always fails when there is html markup (plain text is captured). Am I missing here something? (i.e. a version with negative lookahead?)

Comment: Use `nokogiri`. Perfect gem for this.

Comment: I doubt that nokogiri would help, as I don't have any containers to match against, only comments mark containers in the markup. Jerry's answer did the trick though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can make use of a *positive lookahead*:

```
<!-- #BeginEditable "(Title|Text|Foo)" -->(.*?)(?=<!-- #EndEditable -->)
```

Here's a demo on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/8lI8DcyT0p).

Note I used the m modifier to make the dots match newlines. The dot will thus match every character until it finds `<!-- #EndEditable -->` ahead.